# ¿Cómo conectar un app a un hosting gratuito?

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, servidor

Estoy diseñando un app en Android Studio que pueda guardar ciertos datos como nombre contraseña entre otros, en una base de datos para hacer pruebas en un servidor he utilizado TomCat y Xampp, para la base de datos he utilizado Navicat, en netbeans he creado un WebService para que exista la conexión pero estuve intentando conectar mi WebService a un hosting gratuito y usar crear una base de datos MySQL desde el panel del hosting para conectar mi WebService a aquella base de datos, el problema es que no conecta o no establece una conexión. dejo el código de mi archivo que realiza la conexion y del archivo para probar mi conexión.

Este es el código:

```
public class Conexion {

 private Connection con;
 private final String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
 private final String usuario = "TestBD";
 private final String contrasena = "pass";
 private final String urlBaseDatos = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestBD?serverTimezone=UTC";

 private static Conexion conexion;

 private Conexion(){}

 public static Conexion getInstance() throws SQLException{
    if(conexion == null){
        conexion = new Conexion();
    }
    conexion.conectar();
    return conexion;
 }

 private void conectar() throws SQLException{
     if (con == null || con.isClosed()) {
         try {
         Class.forName(driver);
         } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
         con = DriverManager.getConnection(urlBaseDatos, usuario, contrasena);
     }
 }

 public boolean existeConexion() throws SQLException{
     return con != null && !con.isClosed();
 }

 public Connection getCon() {
     return con;
 }
}
```

Código para probar la conexión:

```
public class TestConexion {
 public static void main(String[] args){
     try {
         if(Conexion.getInstance().existeConexion()){
             System.out.println("Conexión Establecida");
         }
     } catch (SQLException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(TestConexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         System.out.println("Error al Establecer la Conexión");
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: `el problema es que no conecta o no establece una conexión` = ¿cuál de las dos situaciones sucede?, revise si el código genera alguna excepción. Si es así, [edit] la pregunta con los detalles de la excepción.

Comment: Normalmente los hostings gratuitos no te permiten acceder a las BD desde fuera de su localhost. Si lo intentas a tu manera no vas a poder conectar. Debes hacer alguna clase (php?) que reciba la petición http, haga la llamada a BD y devuelva los datos. Vamos, un servicio. En el caso de que no te conecta a tu localhost - como ya te han dicho debes proporcionar algo mas de información - logs etc.